# Skip terraform interpolation inside inline script

Tags: terraform

I have an inline script and I'm trying to do a string replace in bash like this

```
INPUT="Holis"
NEW_VALUE=${INPUT//[A-Z]/_}
```

But terraform thinks I want to do a interpolation with ${}

How can I "skip" this interpolation inside the inline script

Answer (score 4):

Just use double dollar sign at the beginning

```
NEW_VALUE=$${INPUT//[A-Z]/_}
```